# HTML layout conversion to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have a problem with my html layout. I am using CSS `-ms-grid` in order to create a map of points in a specific place on my site. On IE my layout looks exaclty as I wanted, but after conversion to PDF the `-ms-grid` falls apart. Its width fills the entire page. I am using PDF Creator to convert my html.

How can I get my layout to look exactly the same in the PDF file as it does in the browser? Maybe you know a better or faster way of conversion?
I am not a good programist, but I am trying :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the PDF Creator doesn't support the `-ms-grid` CSS property. As you can see in [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid), the support is very limited. If you open your website in another browser, like Chrome or Firefox, the grid will probably look like in your PDF. You have to find another way to do your layout to have it compatible with PDF Creator.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe you know a better way to convert html?